# _cron_queue_info

Tags: cron

worker callback dosen't run in _cron_queue_info

```
function samadiet_cron_queue_info() {
    drupal_set_message("pre run ittttt".date_iso8601(variable_get('samadiet_readsite_queue', time())));

    $queues['samadiet_readsite_queue'] = array(
        'worker callback' => 'samadiet_cron_worker',
        'time' => 1,
    );
    return $queues;

}
function samadiet_cron_worker($item)
{
    drupal_set_message("xxxxx run ittttt".$item);
}
```

no message was show?

Comment: Cron related functions are not the best place to set messages. Log to db or file to reliably determine if it worked. See [watchdog](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you just have declared the queue. You need to invoke `queue` using `DrupalQueue::get('samadiet_readsite_queue')`.

Example to implement :

```
function samadiet_cron(){
  $queue = DrupalQueue::get('samadiet_readsite_queue');
  $queue->createItem($item); // $item argument form samadiet_cron_worker callback
}
```